Golang linter to catch ineffective slice modification class of bugs?
Consider the following golang code:
for _, obj := range myslice {
  obj.Field = <change>
}

The expectation is that in a loop we are changing Field of all elements in the slice. But the reality is that slice will be unchanged at the end of the loop because in each iteration obj is a shallow copy of myslice[i]. The correct implementation would be
for i := range myslice {
  obj := &myslice[i]
  obj.Field = <change>
}

This bug seems very subtle which may escape code reviews as well. Even worse, if the object is a nested struct having some pointer fields than updates to some of the pointer fields may succeed (as it is a shallow copy only). I am looking for a linter, if any, that is capable enough of detecting this code pattern, and flag it as a potential bug to me.
